# Uniform vertical stretch single column contents in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get several buttons to vertically stretch to the size of the container, but I can't figure out how I did it before.  I've tried all of the possibilities on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ (like align-items-stretch, align-self-stretch, align-content-stretch, but none seem to do anything for single column vertical stretching, at least how I implemented them.  How is it done?  Thanks!

(https://codepen.io/jasonws/pen/poyYMpz)

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="d-flex align-content-stretch border" style="height:150px; width:200px; flex-direction: column">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-1">Flex item 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-1">Flex item 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-1">Flex item 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the other things from your d-flex class

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="border" style="display: grid">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-1 m-2">Flex item 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-1 m-2 ">Flex item 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-1 m-2 ">Flex item 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't see how this stretches the buttons vertically in a single column to the height of the container.

Comment: can you please make it more clear, so that I can give any suggestion

Comment: do you want to make your button in the same alignment???

Comment: Thank you for your question!  Do you see how the container height is greater than the height of the buttons, as indicated by the border?  I would like the height of each of the buttons to increase the same small amount so that they completely fill the container.  Does that make the need clearer?

Comment: Thank you for your effort.  I sincerely appreciate it.  Do you see how your buttons are in a row, and the width of each is stretching uniformly to fit the container?  I need the buttons to be in a column, and the height of each button to uniformly stretch to fit the container. My code pen link shows the buttons in a column but without them stretching to fit the container.

Comment: sorry boss I did not get you. is it ok now>

Comment: Thank you very much!  That is exactly what I am looking for.  I'm surprised the answer was so simple.